# Cocoa renaming MyDocument window title

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I change the title of a window in a document based cocoa application? I get an error when I try the following code in MyDocument.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setTitle:@"Document 1"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override [`displayName`](http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-displayName) and return the value you want displayed.

```
- (NSString *)displayName {
    return @"Document 1";
}
```

If you're subclassing `NSWindowController` then override [`windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:`](http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000031-BAJDFCIB) instead.